# Encoding a String to ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, encode, iso-8859-1

Is there a way that a can encode my string `Olá` to `Ol&#225;` in JavaScript? And do this to all accented characters.

My header looks like:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Where does your string come from, and what encoding does it currently have?

Comment: What does the encoding of the `html` file have to do with the string?

Comment: You didn't say whether your JS is running in node.js or elsewhere, but if it is then [`iconv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a proper string, you can do it like this:

**ECMAScript ≥ 6, with Emoji support**

(see: https://medium.com/@giltayar/iterating-over-emoji-characters-the-es6-way-f06e4589516)

```
function decimalEscape(s) {
    let buffer = [];
    for(let ch of s) {
        if(ch.codePointAt(0) <= 127) {
            buffer.push(ch);
        } else {
            buffer.push('&#' + ch.codePointAt(0) + ';');
        }
    }
    return buffer.join('');
}
```

**ECMAScript ≤ 5, without Emoji support:**

```
function decimalEscape(s) {
    var buffer = [];
    for(var i = 0, f = s.length; i < f; ++i) {
        if(s.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {
            buffer.push(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            buffer.push('&#' + s.charCodeAt(i) + ';');
        }
    }
    return buffer.join('');
}
```

Usage:

```
decimalEscape("Olá"); // -> returns "Ol&#225;"
```

If you don't have a proper JavaScript string yet (just a bunch of bytes in some kind of buffer or if the string you have is already in the wrong encoding), you will have to fix the string first, of course.